# A variational problem where the Euler-Lagrange equation contradicts the boundary conditions

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I feel like this should be a no-brainer but this is my first set of variational problems so I'm probably just not used to how it should work.

> Find extremal of $$F[u] = \int_0^1 xuu' dx$$ where $u(0) = 0$ and $u(1) = 1$.

So using the Euler-Lagrange formula with $f(x,u,u') = xuu'$ I get $$0 = f_u - \frac{d}{dx}f_{u'} = xu' - u - xu' = -u$$ so that $u(x) = 0$.

But clearly this does not satisfy the boundary condition, so now what?

Comment: What if we try changing variables: $w = {1 \over 2} u^2$.  So,
$$
u u' = w',
$$
and the problem is now:
$$
\min \rightarrow F[w] = \int_{0}^{1} x \; w' \; dx, \quad w(0)=0, w(1)=1.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is right: there is no extremal function for this problem. Integration by parts makes this clear: 
$$ F[u]= 
\frac12  \int_0^1 x (u^2)'\,dx =  \frac12 xu(x)^2\bigg|_0^1 - \frac12 \int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx = 
\frac12 - \frac12 \int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx $$
Under the given boundary conditions, the integral $\int_0^1 u^2$ can be arbitrarily large, or arbitrarily close to zero — but it cannot be equal to zero, since $u$ cannot be identically zero. Conclusion: 
$\inf_u F[u]=-\infty$, $\sup_u F[u] = 1/2$, and neither one is attained.

The Euler-Lagrange equation correctly suggested what $u$ would have to be to maximize $F$, but $u$ was prevented  from being  that by the boundary conditions.